# replace part of file path via regex

Tags: regex, perl, path

I try to replace directory part of file fullname in Perl.
Something like:
got filename 'D:\Texts1\text1' in directory 'D:\Texts1', want to replace it with 'D:\Texts2' and then filename will be 'D:\Texts2\text1'.

I try this code:

```
$filename = 'D:\Texts1\text1';
$i = 'D:\Texts1';
$o = 'D:\Texts2';
$filename =~ s'$i'$o'g;
```

And it does not take effect. $filename doesn't changes.
I tried to use something like

```
$i = quotemeta('D:\Texts1');
```

but it also has not took effect.

Comment: Thank you all!
My mistake was that I try to use quotemeta to $i and $o at one time. But only for $i it is needed.

Comment: Actually the single quotes were also a problem--see my answer.  You probably changed from single quotes to another delimiter at some point, and this also helped fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't interpolate

```
$filename =~ s'$i'$o'g;
```

try using `/` instead of `'`, like this:

```
$filename =~ s/$i/$o/g;
```

that should work. `'` prevents string interpolation, so the variable names appear as string literals. Also, make sure to use the `quotemeta` like you were doing before.

Comment: They should use forward slashes or escape their backslashes as well.

Comment: The `s` can be followed by any character, including a single quote, and that becomes the delimiter for the regex.  Try: `perl -p -e "s'a'b'g"` and type some a's in the input.

Comment: Technically, you're right, but it's really bad practice... try running [this](http://pastie.org/private/fngidmf5mdmvz2bunthjkg), then [this](http://pastie.org/private/c59ao9idyhejhboo2ogw), and tell me which one works....

Comment: Yea, it is true, you know why s/// works, but s''' doesn't work?

Comment: It is because of the special meaning of single quotes in this context: they prevent variable interpolation.

Comment: +1 @dan1111, I just read it [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):  If "'" is used as the delimiter, no interpolation is done

Comment: +1: The single quotes do seem to suppress the interpolation.  Change them into, say, percent signs and then you can get it to work.  (Slashes are not such a good choice when messing with path names; maybe percents aren't either on Windows because of env vars.)  And I was in no sense claiming that single quotes around the regex was good style; just that it is not disallowed.

Answer (score 2):

There are several valid answers here, I would like to compile a comprehensive answer along with mine to make this post easier to read:

### Root Cause

```
$i = 'D:\Texts1';
```

when used as a regex pattern, "\" should be escaped - what the regex engine want is some ultimate format like: ***D:\\Texts1***. So this doesn't work, however, there are at least 4 different ways to build this format as listed below.

Also to notice, when ' is used as delimiter for match or substitution statement, variable interpolation will be disabled, which renders *$filename =~ s'$i'$o'g;* almost useless. so first step, change it to use / or {}

### Solution 1

use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), this will effectively escape the  "\":

```
$filename = 'D:\Texts1\text1';
$i = quotemeta('D:\Texts1');
$o = 'D:\Texts2';
$filename =~ s/$i/$o/g;
```

### Solution 2

use \Q .. \E, which has similar effects as quotemeta:

```
$filename = 'D:\Texts1\text1';
$i = 'D:\Texts1';
$o = 'D:\Texts2';
$filename =~ s/\Q$i\E/$o/g; # or s/\Q$i/$o/g also works
```

### Solution 3

escape the "\" in the string explicitly, and use [qr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) to quote the string as regex pattern.

```
$filename = 'D:\Texts1\text1';
$i = qr 'D:\\Texts1';
$o = 'D:\Texts2';
$filename =~ s/$i/$o/g;
```

### Solution 4

escape to the extent that the string is ready for regex:

```
$filename = 'D:\Texts1\text1';
$i = 'D:\\\\Texts1';
$o = 'D:\Texts2';
$filename =~ s/$i/$o/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\` in `D:\Texts1` is the problem. You need to escape this metacharacter. For this purpose, the string should be wrapped by `\Q` and `\E`.

```
$filename =~ s/\Q$i\E/$o/g;
```

Comment: You know why escape expicitly doesn't work? $i = 'D:\\Texts'?

Comment: *[lzprgmr](http://stackoverflow.com/users/70198/lzprgmr)*: They are essentially the same: `perl -E 'say "OK" if q{a\b} eq q{a\\b}'`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `\Q`:

```
$filename =~s{\Q$i}{$o};
```

Comment: There's only one variable. \E is not necessary but I guess it would be better style

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are experiencing a combination of two problems:

- Single quotes, while valid as a regexp delimiter, have a special meaning: they disable variable interpolation.  Thus you are searching your string for the literal pattern `$i` (if you have warnings enabled, you get a clue to this--it tells you that the variables $i and $o are only used once in your program).
- As others have pointed out, you also need the `\Q...\E` construct or `quotemeta()` in order to avoid interpreting the special characters in your variable as regexp operators.

Answer (score -1):

Updated code

```
use strict;
use warnings qw/all/;

my $filename = 'D:\Texts1\text1';
my $i = 'D:\\Texts1';
my $o = 'D:\\Texts2';
$filename =~ s/\Q$i\E/$o/;

print $filename;
```

Be happy!

Comment: Do you really want a regex for the replacement text?  I suspect not.

Comment: the quotes in the search and replace are invalid, and `$o` should be `q`, not `qr`, it's not a regex

Comment: @JohnCorbett you know why $i=qr 'D:\\Texts1' works while $i= 'D:\\Texts1' won't work?  we just add the escape ourselves why compared using quotemeta.

Comment: The code will not work as backslashes are escaped to \\ in regular expression pattern, after using \Q and \E to escape backslashes in pattern